# Can't play video

Tags: video, media-player, video-streaming

I just want to know what could be reasons when video can't be played while streaming online though site using flash it shows error can't play video.

I am using Chrome browser on my Sony Xperia SP running Android 4.3 Jelly Bean.

Comment: Which phone are you using? Which Android OS version is installed? Which browser are you trying to view the video on?

Comment: It's xperia sp on 4.3 jelly bean and i am using chrome

Answer (score 0):

It could be because Chrome for Android [does not support Flash](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/faq):

> Chrome for Android will not be supporting Flash. As you may have seen
>   in November, 2011, Adobe announced it has stopped investing in Flash
>   for mobile browsing. Google has long been committed to making the web
>   platform more powerful through open web technologies like HTML5 and is
>   working with Adobe and other partners to further advance the web
>   standard.

Comment: It not just that i was able to play before via chrome and also using mx player app but both does not work now.